# Export OpenGL model as .OBJ

Tags: python, c++, c, opengl, pyopengl

I'm writing a simple PyOpenGL code, with the display part as:

```
glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP)
glVertex2f(0,0)
glVertex2f(0,1)
glVertex2f(1,1)
glVertex2f(1,0)
glEnd()
```

I want to *export* this *model* as a .OBJ file. How can I do this?

I searched for a while, but could only get resources to open a .OBJ model in OpenGL, not vice-versa.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Wavefront (.obj) file format is a pretty simple, text based format. It's relatively easy to read/write. For details, read [this Page on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file)

Your example in Wavefront would be

```
v 0.0 0.0 0.0
v 0.0 1.0 0.0
v 1.0 1.0 0.0
v 1.0 0.0 0.0
f 1 2 3 4
```